# Are short circuit evaluation rules expected at compile time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, templates

**Program A** produces a compilation error (**as expected**) since `isFinite` is called with a non-integral type.

### Program A

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {};

template<typename T>
bool isFinite(const T& t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Called isFinite with a non-integral type");
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << "Foo is finite? " << ((isFinite(f)) ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

However, a slight modification (see **Program B**) allows the program to compile (Visual Studio 2013) and produce the following output.

### Program B Visual Studio 2013 Ouput

`Foo is finite? yes`

### Program B

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {};

template<typename T>
bool isFinite(const T& t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Called isFinite with a non-integral type");
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << "Foo is finite? " << ((true || isFinite(f)) ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It appears that **Program B** is short circuiting on the logical OR operation and not attempting to compile the rest of the expression. **However**, this application does not compile using g++ 4.8.3 (`g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp`). I get the following output.

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'bool isFinite(const T&) [with T = Foo]':
main.cpp:15:56:   required from here
main.cpp:8:2: error: static assertion failed: Called isFinite with a non-integral type
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Called isFinite with a non-integral type");
  ^
```

My intuition leads me to believe that the compilation failure is the correct behavior **but it is curious that Visual Studio 2013 compiles successfully**. My intuition is based on the fact that it is expected that the following code cannot be compiled.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    void doOperation1() {}
    void doOperation2() {}
};

struct Bar
{
    void doOperationA() {}
    void doOperation2() {}
};

template<typename T>
void performOperation(T& t, bool value)
{
    if (value)
    {
        t.doOperation1();
    }
    else
    {
        t.doOperation2();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    performOperation(f, true);
    performOperation(f, false);

    Bar b;
    performOperation(b, false); // Fails to compile (as expected)

    return 0;
}
```

### Restated Question

Are the logical operators supposed to adhere to short circuit evaluation rules **at compile time** (i.e., what is the expected compilation behavior of **Program B**)?

Comment: @TonyD Perhaps I'm misreading the documentation but [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_infinity) it appears that the *unspecialized* case always returns `false`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I get the same behavior if I replace `has_infinity` with a hard-coded `true`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tagged you by accident, I corrected my comment

Comment: James/Matt: yes - good point re unspecialised value.  Anyway, short circuit evaluation is about not having the false path evaluated... in this case the function call `std::isfinite(Zoo)` is *invalid* at compile time - there's no such overload - so I don't see that the compiler's obliged to accept it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Fair point, I replaced the usage of `numeric_limits` with `true`

Comment: Maybe this is a tricky question, the g++ error messages seem to indicate that it is using SFINAE in `std::isfinite(f)` and IDK what happens when you do that behind the short-circuit operator

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I edited the errors. Yes, I too saw the application of SFINAE via `std::enable_if` but I don't know if that is a contributing factor.

Comment: I have updated the question to remove the parts that were unnecessary and possibly causing unnecessary distractions as well.

Comment: What happens if you disable optimization (`/Od`) in Visual Studio? Could it be possible that Visual Studio is doing something weird and optimizing out `true || isFinite(f)` before the template is instantiated?

Comment: @AtlasC1 I was already compiling a *Debug* build and I verified this configuration is using `/Od`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short circuit is not supposed to compile `true || (whatever_ill_formed)`. `isFinite<Foo>` is instantiated as part of expression and during instantiation it should be compiled and during compilation it should static assert. After that the compiler may never evaluate `isFinite<Foo>(f)` because of short circuit but static assert is not supposed to happen during it.

It is unclear why Visual Studio 2013 compiles Program B. Standard only allows bypassing syntax checking of templates when template is never instantiated. Even then the code is still ill formed only diagnostics are not required. Behind the defect is perhaps the same internal issue in Visual C++ that does not let Microsoft to implement `constexpr`.

**Edit** I add some language lawyer texts from standard per @zneak request

3.2/3

> A function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is
>   odr-used if it is the unique lookup result or the selected member of a
>   set of overloaded functions (3.4, 13.3, 13.4), unless it is a pure
>   virtual function and its name is not explicitly qualified. [Note: This
>   covers calls to named functions (5.2.2), operator overloading (Clause
>   13), user-defined conversions (12.3.2), allocation function for
>   placement new (5.3.4), as well as non-default initialization (8.5). A
>   constructor selected to copy or move an object of class type is
>   odr-used even if the call is actually elided by the implementation
>   (12.8). —end note]

5.13/1

> The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4). It returns true if either
>   of its operands is true, and false otherwise. Unlike |, || guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not
>   evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.

7.1/4

> In a static_assert-declaration the constant-expression shall be a
>   constant expression (5.19) that can be contextually converted to bool
>   (Clause 4). If the value of the expression when so converted is true,
>   the declaration has no effect. Otherwise, the program is ill-formed,
>   and the resulting diagnostic message (1.4) shall include the text of
>   the string-literal, except that characters not in the basic source
>   character set (2.3) are not required to appear in the diagnostic
>   message.

14.7.1/3

> Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template
>   specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist.

Comment: Careful there: we're treading into language lawyer territory. The right-hand part of `true || isFinite(x)` is definitely not a syntax error, and it would help the credibility of your answer if it had the right terms and a handful of standard quotes.

Comment: @zneak The function definition is still required to exist because there is call in right operand of ||. It is regardless if the call is evaluated. If the definition must exists then it must be implicitly instantiated and static assert in the instantiation makes the whole program ill-formed. I add some texts from standard.

Comment: Just as a matter of record, Visual Studio 2022 **still** compiles Program B , even with `/permissive-`.  But if I add a variable `int i = 1;` then substituting `((i==1) || isFinite(f))` causes the expected compilation failure.